# Wired internet not working on 16.04 after reboot

Tags: networking, 16.04

I can't ping my PFSense box or 8.8.8.8.  My NIC on my motherboard was working then stopped after reset so I just bought a new Intel Pro NIC that worked, but now after a reset after a few days I can't get it to come up.  I am pretty new to Linux, but I have been googling and trying for days to get this to work.  I wanted to reach out to the community before I had to start all over since loading everything back up takes me almost 8 hours to get all my media share set back up correctly.  Any ideas?

Output of etc/network/interfaces is: (I am having to manually type it since it is a headless server that I can't SSH into).

(sorry the below are on individual lines, I just don't know how to make them appear that way in the actual body) - total noob here.

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp129s0f0
iface enp129s0f0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.232
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 broadcast 182.168.1.255
 gateway 182.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 182.168.1.1.8.8.8.8

(I know it isn't set to eth0, but my onboard NIC is still set to that, and I had it working before but it just stopped now).

I have also swapped it to a new spot on the motherboard.

Also tried all of these with no luck:

sudo ifdown -a
sudo ifup -a
sudo dhclient enp128s0f0
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo iptables -F

i manually edited /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules to include the mac address of the new card (it wasn't showing automatically) and also kept the KERNAL=='eth*', NAME="enp129s0f0"

Ouput of iplink shows 8 items - all are DOWN except lo which is UNKNOWN and enp129s0f0 which is UP:

lo
enp7s0
enp8s0
enp12s0
enp13s0
enp129s0f0
enp129s0f1
docker0

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: for enp129s0f0 it is: link encap:Ethernet HWaddr (mac address) inet addr:192.168.1.232 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe...UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric 1 RX packets:4314 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets 3372 errors: 0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:1381611 (1.3 MB) TX bytes:267825 (267.8 KB) Interrupt:16 Memory:fbea000-fbec0000

Comment: what about `netstat -rn`

Answer (score 1):

I may not have the answer, but I know that I'll help you, provided that what I see is accurate.

**UDEV**

It is not common to need to manipulate files in UDEV unless you're trying to rename how interfaces appear or set some custom values. Keep in mind that to make networking operate in general, you should not needed to be messing with UDEV files. Please, any time you modify a system file, make a backup first.

**Static Addresses**

You're using a static address. Unless you have a very specific need for a static address, you should use DHCP and then set the ip reservation from the router, based on MAC address, instead. Given your current setup, did you also make an IP reservation in your router? If not you could have another device with the same IP that is conflicting with your server. I've seen this plenty of times in both home and corporate networks where someone set a static address within the same range as the DHCP lease pool: Game over. There will be IP address conflicts until one of the devices goes away.

**Different network ranges**

I don't know if this is a typo or real. Look carefully at the addresses. They're not in the same range. Some of your addresses start with 192.168.x.x and others with 182.168.x.x. It doesn't matter if you want 192 or 182, but it DOES matter if you are not consistent with every single device on your network.

Typically in a home environment you should see this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto <interfaceName>
iface <interfaceName> inet dhcp
```

If you were adamant on static addresses, make sure it is similar to the following:

```
auto enp129s0f0
iface enp129s0f0 inet static
address 192.168.1.232
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

^^ If you do the above ^^  make sure that you set a portion of the address range on the router (bottom end or top end) outside of the DHCP range. You cannot ever assign 192.168.1.1 because that's your router (gateway) and you shouldn't assign 192.168.1.255 because that's your broadcast address. You also don't use 192.168.1.0 because that just means you're on subnet x.x.1.x and any address from .1 through .255 is valid on your network.

```
Low end static range: 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.30
DHCP remaining: 192.168.1.31 - 192.168.1.254
  -or-
DHCP lower: 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.230
Upper end static: 192.168.1.231 - 192.168.1.254
```

Those are just examples. Carve out what you need. Normally you will use static sparingly. If you're not managing a big network, just leave it DHCP and set reservations in the router or you may encounter conflicts and or communication issues.

Also, you need to read up on systemd if the above doesn't set you straight. Starting in 16.04, networking is managed by systemd, to an extent. That's why your interface name now appears as enp129s0f0 and not the old eth0 like in 14.04 and earlier. This is the result of predictive interface naming in systemd.

---

**Food for thought**

Based on your comments about being new, not knowing how to format on this page, and also not knowing how to copy stuff exactly, I'll give you a few examples:

Forgive me if you already know. The basics in linux

```
Command with no options:
    command

Command with a file path:
    command /filePath/file

Command with options and file path:
    command -option /filePath/file

Get help on a command:
    command -h
       -or-
    command --help

Read the manual page:
    man command

Show attached disks:
    lsblk

Show mount points:
    mount

Remove a drive:
    umount /path

Change into another directory (folder):
     cd /path

Copy a file:
    cp /path-to-file /path-to-destination

Make a file:
    touch /path/fileName

Make a directory (folder):
    mkdir folderName

Edit a file:
    vim /path/fileName

Reference to this folder:
    ./

Reference to parent folder:
    ../
```

Get a flash drive plugged into your computer and type `mount`. Find the path to your flash drive and then type `cd /` and append the path you see listed from `mount`. Type `pwd` and make sure you're inside the path to the flash drive. from here, use the shell copy and file like this:

```
If you have to copy files:
    cp /path/file ./

If you have to, make a file:
    touch ./myFile
```

When you need to read output like `ifconfig` or `ls -la`, just write the output to a file by using pipe. (command + pipe + command + append + file)

```
Example:
    ifconfig -a | cat >> myFile

Validate by printing the file to the screen
    cat myFile

Finished?
    umount /filePath
```

Now, this forum. above where you type, there is a "links, images, styles/headers, block quotes, etc...." Read that. It tells you how to format. back ticks, four spaces, > symbols, etc....

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, yes the 182 above was a typo.  I have gone back and changed it to dhcp and reserved the IP address on the pfsense box.  No issues there, but it did not fix the probelm.  Your post was very helpful on a few other areas and I thank you for taking the time to share this.

Comment: So you set the server to inet dhcp and then did an ip reservation at the router but no luck? Did you by chance restart anything? If that's all set, on your server, try this: `sudo dhclient -r enp129s0f0` Then follow up with `sudo -4 enp129s0f0`. That should revoke or clean up the way for the following IPv4 DHCP lease request. See if that helps. --Edit--> I've had issues where a connection tries to use IPv6 and I have to specify IPv4.