# I restart my computer and the ethernet doesn't work any more

Tags: networking, ethernet

## Note: I don't have any Wireless cards (or whatever it is) so Wireless Internet wouldn't be an option :/

## SOLUTION: After turning it off for a bit, it instantly connected when logging in. I can also confirm this works. Yay, I guess?

So, before this restart, I just finished setting up nginx for my website and then I thought:

"Would the website stay working if I restarted?" (since I am so unlucky in life apparently)

So I restarted and boom. The ethernet for both Windows and Ubuntu stopped working. They just won't pick up the router connection (through the ethernet cable) anymore.

I don't have any WiFi/Ethernet management tools installed so I can't really do anything that requires downloads.

I really don't know what to do.

#### I do remember that this happened when installing Ubuntu however it fixed itself somehow (I think after a restart, idk lol) but this isn't working now so...

I can give you all the details you need but since I am posting this on a MacBook... I really can't copy and paste stuff over so yeah.

Just make sure that if your way of fixing this solution is through the command line then make sure all commands are built-in to the system as, again: I DO NOT HAVE ANY APT-GET INSTALL TOOLS FOR INTERNET!

## I also tried 5 solutions on here too and they didn't help either :(

Here are the solutions I have tried:

| Solution | Worked |
| --- | --- |
| [Solution 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009227/network-is-disabled-every-time-i-reboot-ubuntu-16-04-lts-webserver) | Nope |
| [Solution 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176055/no-internet-after-reboot-without-restarting-networking-service) | Not in a MILLION YEARS! |
| [Solution 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325393/ethernet-not-working-after-reboot-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-2) | No |
| [Solution 4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/no-connection-after-reboot) | Pfft... as if |
| [Solution 5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843369/wired-internet-not-working-on-16-04-after-reboot) | Are these even "solutions" anymore? |

Please, someone save me from this ethernet heck.

Comment: I think you should provide how exactly those solutions not working

Comment: "*The ethernet for both Windows and Ubuntu stopped working. They just won't pick up the router connection (through the ethernet cable) anymore.*" This suggests that you have a bad cable or other hardware fault. Were it software, it would affect it's own OS, but never both OS.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Both my router and PC is in the font room but I need a long ethernet cable to get to the router as it's about 5-7m away (I forgot how long a meter was lol)

Comment: After turning it off for a bit, it instantly connected when logging in. I can also confirm this works. Yay, I guess?

Comment: Wow, you seem like a very wealthy person. Most of us cannot afford a font room. My fonts must reside inside my computer, stored as data. A whole room for fonts would be great.